# How do I write an update statement when the attribute I am updating is user input?

Tags: python, sql

```
def updateNurseSpecification():

    nurse_lname = input("\nEnter the last name of the nurse "
                    "you would to update: \n")

    query = c.execute('SELECT fname, lname, specification FROM Nurses '
                  'WHERE lname LIKE ?', (nurse_lname,))

    new_spec = input("\nEnter the updated specification of this employee: \n")

    query1 = c.execute('UPDATE Nurses SET specification = ', (new_spec,)
                  ' WHERE lname LIKE ?', (nurse_lname,))
```

I do not know the syntax in order to update the record with the variable "new_spec".

```
    print("Your update is as shown: \t")

    query2 = c.execute('SELECT fname, lname, specification FROM Nurses'
                 'WHERE lname LIKE ?', (nurse_lname,))
```

Comment: You're passing a tuple of parameters, which gets unpacked into the placeholders. Try `c.execute('UPDATE Nurses SET specification = ? WHERE lname LIKE ?', (new_spec, nurse_lname))`

Answer (score 2):

`execute` takes two parameters - an SQL string and a tuple of arguments:

```
c.execute('UPDATE Nurses SET specification = %s WHERE lname LIKE %s', 
          (new_spec, nurse_lname))
```